# jquery get element by name and set indexer from variable

Tags: jquery

Say I want get an element via its name and it's an item in the list. I need to specify  what index it is. I'm getting the value for the index from another element:

```
var testid = $(this).data('testid');
$('[name="TestDtos["' + testid + '"].Save"]').val(this.checked);
```

So say the testid was 7 I would want it to read:

```
$('[name="TestDtos[7].Save"]').val(this.checked);
```

So the value of the index comes through fine. The problem I think is when I try to add the testid value inside the "[]". Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I'm not really sure what I'm doing here.

Comment: `.Save` is part of a name too? not a css class?

Comment: You may need to escape the dot in your name with backslashes: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had extra double quotes. It should be,

```
var testid = $(this).data('testid');
$('[name="TestDtos[' + testid + '].Save"]').val(this.checked);
```